# How to look up information based off a single cell? In Excel

Tags: excel

I've been working on VBA for so long I forgot how to do this...using formulas.

I have a cell that has a descriptor in it, in this case K1122121. The cell next to it, will be the description. On another sheet I have a list of parts, I need to look up said part number on sheet 2, and place the description next to the part it's looking up.

I know it's possible, I just forget how.

So to recap.

Sheet one has two cells, the first is a part number, the 2nd next to it, is where the formula is going, in this cell will produce the description to said part number.

Sheet two has part and description side by side. I need to reference the part number and find the description.

Once the description is found, place said description in the description field in sheet one.

Thanks for the help.

Here is a link of what I am working on. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/PAERTO.xlsm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was a little more complex than I was hoping, but I ended up using this as an answer. It may not be the most simplistic, or elegant, but it works.

`=IF(E20=0,VLOOKUP("*"&E20&"*",'Jobs List'!D:E,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP("*"&E20&"*",'JL Archive'!D:E,2,FALSE))`

I used the `"*"` to make it so that it utilized wild cards, something I never thought of using... but it works. I put the wildcard usage in front and behind so just in case any cells may have something more than the required text in the front of the part or behind it.

I hope this helps people. The original use for this was so I can use the formula can be used from another workbook, but as we all know this can be used anywhere. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

It's called `VLOOKUP` and you call it like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Where:

- `A1` is the cell with the part number in sheet1
- `Sheet2` the sheet where the data is located (descriptor / description)
- `A:B` is the range in sheet2 where the data is located
- `2` because what you are looking for is in the second column
- `FALSE` to only get a value for exact matches - if no exact match is found, it will show an error

**EDIT**

Looking at your workbook, I would personally insert a new column in the jobs list (say between D and E) with a formula that only keeps the first word only - formula in E3:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",D3)),D3,LEFT(D3,FIND(" ",D3)-1))
```

Then the formula in the PAERTO sheet then becomes - formula in D20:

```
=VLOOKUP($E20,'Jobs List'!$E:$F,2,FALSE)
```

in the example you provided, I get a result for lines 20, 22 and 24, and an error on the other lines.

Comment: This really isn't viable. I understand why you suggest that, but this workbook the way it is right now is as close to a living document as it's original counterpart. Is there a way to only search the first part of the name instead of all of it?

Comment: @MattRidge I think it is possible with a `LOOKUP` and an array function but I am not sure how to do it. I suggest you post a separate question "vlookup where the lookup-value is the first word of a cell in the table array?" or something like that.

Comment: Well the problem seems to be that the lookup formula is pulling the last item in the list. in Jobs List, instead of actually finding the correct one in the first place.

Comment: lookup (not vlookup) can do really powerful stuff but is rather complicated to use. I'm sure there is a way, I just don't know how!

Comment: @MattRidge Insert a helper column, use a formula to extract the part #, then hide the column.

Comment: Actually did something like this: `=IF(E20=0,VLOOKUP("*"&E20&"*",'[Open Order Report v10.xlsm]Jobs List'!D:E,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP("*"&E20&"*",'[Open Order Report v10.xlsm]JL Archive'!D:E,2,FALSE))`

Answer (score 2):

I can get a result if I use this formula:

`=VLOOKUP(E20&" Rev"&F20,'Jobs List'!D:E,2,0)`

However you need to change cell `F20` to `4`.

As long as part number and "Rev" are consistent between sheets, this formula should work.

Note that only cells `D20` and `D24` return values. The other part numbers don't exist on the other sheet, so regardless of what formula is used you will not see a return value.

Comment: The reason I can't do that is because the description may not always end with Rev, it may end with "rev", "REV, or /, or \, or -, or something entirely different. I think I'll stick with what I did.

Answer (score 1):

With your part number in A1, in B1 the formula `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)` will find the description

If you are on Excel 2003 or earlier, you will have to change `Sheet2!A:B` to be a full reference like `Sheet2!A2:B2000`

Comment: I'm answering both here.This is what I have here, and had before I posted... and the reason I am asking, because I though VLOOKUP would work: `=VLOOKUP($E20,'[Open Order Report v10.xlsm]Jobs List'!$D:$E,2,TRUE)` It doesn't work.  It should, but it doesn't. The reason I have it as TRUE is because the part sometimes has a rev at the end, or doesn't so I make it so it will work just in case.

Comment: @MattRidge it doesn't work as in? You get an error? You don't get the expected value?

Comment: with `TRUE`, the data has to be sorted, and it will get the next biggest value. e.g if you have `PART-A` followed by `PART-B`, when you search for `PART-A REV 1`, it will give you the description for `PART-B`

Comment: If I change it to TRUE I get a #NA, even though I know for a fact the part number is there, although it has Rev A, Rev C and Rev D in each version though.

Comment: @MattRidge I suggest you update your question with a specific example (descriptor, description, value you are trying to find, formula you use, result you get, result you expect).